# Digital signal decimation using gnuradio lib

Tags: c++, signal-processing, gnuradio

I write application where I must process digital signal - array of double. I must the signal decimate, filter etc.. I found a project gnuradio where are functions for this problem. But I can't figure how to use them correctly.

I need signal decimate (for example from 250Hz to 200Hz). The function should be similar to resample function in Matlab. I found, the classes for it are:

- rational_resampler_base_fff Class [source](http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1filter_1_1kernel_1_1pfb__arb__resampler__fff.html#aa20ea875526c9a6c01233425836e2124)
- fir_filter_fff Class [source](http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1filter_1_1kernel_1_1pfb__arb__resampler__fff.html#aa20ea875526c9a6c01233425836e2124)
- ...

Unfortunately I can't figure how to use them.

gnuradio and shared library I have installed

Thanks for any advice

## EDIT to @jcoppens

Thank you very much for you help.
But I must process signal in my code. I find classes in gnuradio which can solve my problem, but I need help how set them.

Functions which I must set are:
**low_pass(doub gain, doub sampling_freq, doub cutoff_freq, doub transition_width, window, beta)**
where:

> use "window method" to design a low-pass FIR filter
> **gain**: overall gain of filter (typically 1.0)
> **sampling_freq**: sampling freq (Hz)
> **cutoff_freq**: center of transition band (Hz)
> **transition_width**: width of transition band (Hz).
> The normalized width of the transition band is what sets the number of taps required. Narrow –> more taps
> **window_type**: What kind of window to use. Determines maximum attenuation and passband ripple.
> **beta**: parameter for Kaiser window

I know, I must use window = KAISER and beta = 5, but for the rest I'm not sure.

The func which I use are: [low_pass](http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1filter_1_1kernel_1_1pfb__arb__resampler__fff.html#aa20ea875526c9a6c01233425836e2124) and [pfb_arb_resampler_fff::filter](http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1filter_1_1kernel_1_1pfb__arb__resampler__fff.html#aa20ea875526c9a6c01233425836e2124)

**UPDATE:**

I solved the resampling using [libsamplerate](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/)

Answer (score 2):

> I need signal decimate (for example from 250Hz to 200Hz)

WARNING: I expressed the original introductory paragraph incorrectly - my apologies.

As 250 Hz is not related directly to 200 Hz, you have to do some tricks to convert 250Hz into 200Hz. Inserting 4 interpolated samples in between the 250Hz samples, lowers the frequency to 50Hz. Then you can raise the frequency to 200Hz again by decimating by a factor 4.

For this you need the "Rational Resampler", where you can define the subsample and decimate factors. Something like this:

[image]

This means you would have to do something similar if you use the library. Maybe it's even simpler to do it without the library. Interpolate linearly between the 250 Hz samples (i.e. insert 4 extra samples between each), then decimate by selecting each 4th sample.

Note: There is a Signal Processing forum on stackexchange - maybe this question might fall in that category...

More information: If you only have to resample your input data, and you do not need the actual gnuradio program, then have a look at this document:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/resample.pdf

There are several links to other documents, and a link to `libresample`, `libresample4`, and others, which may be of use to you. Another, very interesting, page is:

http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/resampling

Finally, from the same source as the pdf above, check their `snd` program. It may solve your problem without writing *any* software. It can load floating point samples, resample, and save again:

http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/software/soundapps.html#SECTION00062100000000000000

EDIT: And yet another solution - maybe the simplest of all: Use Matlab (or the free Octave version):

```
pkg load signal
t = linspace(0, 10*pi, 50);  % Generate a timeline - 5 cycles
s = sin(t);                  % and the sines -> 250 Hz
tr = resample(s, 5, 4);      % Convert to 200 Hz
plot(t, s, 'r')              % Plot 250 Hz in red
hold on
plot(t, tr(1:50))            % and resampled in blue
```

Will give you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have any experience with DSP. 

I will find out how many times i must to perform interpolation and decimation. 
And after that I can use rational_resampler_base_fff Class [link](http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1filter_1_1rational__resampler__base__fff.html). Do you know how to use it in code?

Comment: Thank you, I explore the links.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me set some variables by which I don't know what they mean.

Comment: If I were you, I'd ask on the https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio list. You'll find lots of knowledgeable people over there. I'd also consider the other answer above - libresample.

Comment: Thanks. I will turn for advice there. But I tried to use libresample and it seems that it works.